# Using Phonegap events on Angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I generated the skeleton of the app with phonegap-angular-seed and he created a factory with the phonegap event deviceready according to this [link](https://github.com/thewildpendulum/angular-phonegap-seed/blob/master/js/services.js). How should I call this event properly on my Angularjs controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is just a simple service that returns a callback function for your use once the event has fired.

First you need to add the dependency for the service in your module definition.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['App.services']);
```

Then you can inject the cordovaReady into your controller.

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'cordovaReady', function($scope, cordovaReady) {
     cordovaReady(function () {
         // Device ready event has fired when this function fires
     });
}]);
```

Comment: cordovaready is the factory name but how can i call deviceready event on controller??

Comment: cordovaReady takes a function as a parameter, this function is called when the device ready event is fired. Look above